# Select error : ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get some data from 2 synonyms by specific `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER` but I get an error

```
SELECT n.NAME_A, m.MOTHER_NAME_A
FROM S_S_CSPF_NRS_PERSON_V N, S_S_CSPF_NRS_MOTHER_V  M
WHERE BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER = 1111111
```

Comment: Can you share the tables' structures please?

Comment: its secured synonyms i cant see its structures

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Using the old style join syntax is especially discouraged because it's a lot easier to make a mistake and not realise. You have no join conditions between your tables - you probably wanted there to be some sort of relation between the two... cc @marc_s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER` column exists in both `S_S_CSPF_NRS_PERSON_V` and `S_S_CSPF_NRS_MOTHER_V`.

You need to specify it too. Either:

```
where n.BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER = 1111111
```

or:

```
where m.BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER = 1111111
```

Also, what is `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER` data type? Varchar?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use an alias with the `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER` column in your `WHERE` clause.  I will assume that this column belongs to the `S_S_CSPF_NRS_PERSON_V` table, so the query should be:

```
SELECT n.NAME_A, m.MOTHER_NAME_A
FROM S_S_CSPF_NRS_PERSON_V n, S_S_CSPF_NRS_MOTHER_V m
WHERE n.BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER = 1111111
```

You are currently doing a cross join between the two tables.  If this is what you intended, then leave it as is.  If you intended an `INNER JOIN`, then why not make it explicit:

```
SELECT n.NAME_A, m.MOTHER_NAME_A
FROM S_S_CSPF_NRS_PERSON_V n
INNER JOIN S_S_CSPF_NRS_MOTHER_V m
    ON n.col1 = m.col2
WHERE n.BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER = 1111111
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question:  I am getting an ORA-00918 error on my SQL select statement
>   that joins two tables.  How do I correct this ORA-00918 error?
>   Answer:  The Oracle docs note this on the ora-00918 error::\ ORA-00918
>   column ambiguously defined
>
> Cause: A column name used in a join exists in more than one table and
>   is thus referenced ambiguously. In a join, any column name that occurs
>   in more than one of the tables must be prefixed by its table name when
>   referenced. The column should be referenced as TABLE.COLUMN or
>   TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN. For example, if tables EMP and DEPT are being
>   joined and both contain the column DEPTNO, then all references to
>   DEPTNO should be prefixed with the table name, as in EMP.DEPTNO or
>   E.DEPTNO.
>
> Action: Prefix references to column names that exist in multiple
>   tables with either the table name or a table alias and a period (.),
>   as in the examples above.
>
> When ORA-00918 is thrown, you have a column which has been ambiguously
>   defined.  If a column name in a join is referenced ambiguously, it
>   exists in multiple tables.
>
> Column names which occur in multiple tables should be prefixed when it
>   is referenced by its table name. Columns must be referenced as
>   TABLE.COLUMN or TABLE_ALIAS.COLUM .  Oracle documentation which
>   reference ORA-00918 give the following example:
>         - If tables EMP and DEPT are being joined and both contain the column DEPTNO, then all references to DEPTNO should be prefixed with
>   the table name, as in EMP.DEPTNO or E.DEPTNO.
>
> To correct ORA-00918, references should be prefixed to column names
>   existing in multiple tables (either with the table name or table alias
>   and a period) [source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm)

So, tho you define `n.NAME_A, m.MOTHER_NAME_A` with a prefix `n` or `m`, you don't define `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER` which probably causes the error.

To fix this, add a prefix to the `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER`!

Answer (score 0):

its working in this way thanks a lot guys

```
 select n.NAME_A ,m.MOTHER_NAME_A from S_S_CSPF_NRS_PERSON_V n
     ,S_S_CSPF_NRS_MOTHER_V m  
where n.BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER = 111111
     and M.BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER= 1111111
```

Comment: That would be unnecessary; you have already joined the tables using `BENEFICIARY_CIVIL_NUMBER`, so in the `WHERE` clause you just have to specify it once...